# Grails: Using a CRUD GSP as a template

Tags: grails

I have a UserController which is mostly CRUD. and i autogenerated it using the generate view in spring toolsuite

It made a user folder in view and containts list,_form,create,edit,show GSPs.

```
package rms

import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

class UserController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
}

def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [userInstanceList: User.list(params), userInstanceTotal: User.count()]
}

def create() {
    [userInstance: new User(params)]
}

def save() {
    def userInstance = new User(params)
    if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance.id)
}

def show(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [userInstance: userInstance]
}

def edit(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [userInstance: userInstance]
}

def update(Long id, Long version) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (version != null) {
        if (userInstance.version > version) {
            userInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this User while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    userInstance.properties = params

    if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance.id)
}

def delete(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    try {
        userInstance.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
}
```

I have a created an admin GSP under view. It has a header, a footer then a sidebar. The contents should be under the div with the class=col-xs-10. I cannot post image yet

```
<html>
<head>
       <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="basic"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css/RMS', file: 'non-responsive.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css/RMS', file: 'style.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css/RMS/personnel', file: 'admin.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css/RMS/personnel', file: 'tabs.css')}" type="text/css" media="screen">   
</head>
<body>

<g:render template="/layouts/headerAdmin"></g:render>

<div id="wrap">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="sticker">
            <li><a href="admin-reports.html"><strong>Reports</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="admin-tables.html"><strong>Manage Tables</strong></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="admin-employees.html"><strong>Manage Employees</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="admin-menu.html"><strong>Manage Menu</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="admin-inventory.html"><strong>Inventory</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="admin-pos.html"><strong>Point of Sales</strong></a></li>         
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  });
</script>

</body>
```

How do you use the user GSPs as templates in the admin GSP, so that the tables will appear in the admin? Basically the list gsp shows the database tables. This is whats in the list gsps btw

```
<%@ page import="rms.User" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User')}" />
    <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#list-user" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
            <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="list-user" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="username" title="${message(code: 'user.username.label', default: 'Username')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="password" title="${message(code: 'user.password.label', default: 'Password')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="dateOfBirth" title="${message(code: 'user.dateOfBirth.label', default: 'Date Of Birth')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="contactNumber" title="${message(code: 'user.contactNumber.label', default: 'Contact Number')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="employeeID" title="${message(code: 'user.employeeID.label', default: 'Employee ID')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="employeeStatus" title="${message(code: 'user.employeeStatus.label', default: 'Employee Status')}" />

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${userInstanceList}" status="i" var="userInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${userInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "username")}</g:link></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "password")}</td>

                    <td><g:formatDate date="${userInstance.dateOfBirth}" /></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "contactNumber")}</td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "employeeID")}</td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "employeeStatus")}</td>

                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate controller="user" total="${userInstanceTotal}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking asking how to show the user controller list action inside that div, you would do:

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <g:include controller="user" action="list" />
</div>
```

You can read more here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/include.html

But what I think you are really after would be creating a Layout that can be used on all admin pages. You can read more about that here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#layouts

The layout would apply styling to any GSP that you apply it to, so you could create an "admin" layout then in your CRUD GSP you could go:

```
<meta name="layout" content="admin" />
```

Inside the `<head>` tag.

Comment: I used the include tag like above. and it showed the list gsp. but that gsp has a g:sortablecolumn tag and whenever i sort one of the table headers it doesnt sort under the admin page but to the user/list like this user/list?sort=username&max=10&order=asc

Comment: Yea, its because you are including the rendered output of the user controller list action. Which if I remember correctly will create all links for the user controller. I would recommend you look at the layout option as it will be much cleaner and easier to implement. You would basically move admin.gsp to under "grails-app/views/layouts" and then under the "col-xs-10" div place "<g:layoutBody />". then use what I said above as the meta tag in the head of any GSP wanting the "admin" layout.